# как вернуть видимость ListFragment

Tags: android

Все доброго времени суток, при написании программы столкнулся с проблемой, у меня есть заполненный `ListFragment`:

```
public class PvPMap extends ListFragment{

ListView map;
FrameLayout fl;
Fragment permafrost;
Fragment river;
Fragment reactor;
Fragment oil;
Fragment mountain;
Fragment island;
Fragment cold;
Fragment pis;
Fragment fire;
Fragment air;

FragmentManager manager;
FragmentTransaction transaction;


String [] mapname = new String[] {"Вечная мерзлота","Тихая река","Реактор","Нефтепровод","Предгорье",
        "Затеряный остров","Холодная сталь","Мирный рубеж","Горящий песок","Воздушная тревога"};
int [] mapimg = new int[] {R.drawable.permafrost, R.drawable.river, R.drawable.reaktor, R.drawable.oil, R.drawable.mauntain,
        R.drawable.island, R.drawable.cold, R.drawable.pis, R.drawable.fire, R.drawable.air};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View pvp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_pvp, container, false);

    permafrost = new Permafrost();
    river = new River();
    reactor = new Reactor();
    oil = new Oil();
    mountain = new Mauntain();
    island = new Island();
    cold = new Cold();
    pis = new Pis();
    fire = new Fire();
    air = new Air();


    fl = (FrameLayout) pvp.findViewById(R.id.conteiner);
    map = (ListView) pvp.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mapname.length; i++){
        HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
        m.put("name", mapname[i]);            
        m.put("img", Integer.toString(mapimg[i]));
        aList.add(m);
    }

    String[] from = {"name", "img"};

    int [] to = {R.id.textViewMap, R.id.imageViewMap};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.list_item, from, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return pvp;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, permafrost);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 1:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, river);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 2:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, reactor);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 3:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, oil);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 4:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, mountain);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 5:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, island);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 6:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, cold);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 7:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, pis);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 8:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, fire);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 9:
            fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            map.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            transaction.add(R.id.conteiner, air);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;

    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

при нажатии на элемент, как видно, я скрываю `ListFragment`, а вызываемый фрагмент делаю видимым, но проблема заключается в том что при нажатии кнопки "Back" и возврати к `ListFragment`, он все ровно остаётся невидимым, пока не выйду из `acivity` и не зайду снова. Как можно решить этот казус?

XML-файл

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/conteiner"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для отображения новых фрагментов не `transaction.add()`, а `transaction.replace()` - тогда не придется скрывать фрагмент со списком, потому что будет производиться замена фрагментов, а не добавление к уже существующему. Кнопка "назад" будет корректно работать при этом.

то есть кейсы примут примерно такой вид:

```
    case 0:
        transaction.replace(R.id.conteiner, permafrost);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        break;
```

так же очень желательно почитать [официальное руководство](http://developer-android.unlimited-translate.org/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) по этой теме, в частности по [замене фрагментов](http://developer-android.unlimited-translate.org/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace).

Comment: заменил  .add на .replace и теперь этот элемент вообще перестал реагировать на нажатие, но если нажать на не изменённый элемент, то есть с .add,то открываются оба фрагмента, фрагмент с .add поверх фрагмента .replace

Comment: @Crown_Clown Я вот заметил, что у вас список и выбор в списке располагаются в разных контейнерах (map и fl), c чем это связано, они располагаются в разных частях экрана и занимают только часть его?

Comment: Это я нашёл как вариант работы с выбором в ListView. Добавил FrameLayout который у меня является контейнером для выбраного фрагмента из списка, и попробовал это применить к выбору и в ListFragment

Comment: @Crown_Clown Вам нужно использовать один и тот же контейнер и для фрагмента с списком и для того фрагмента, что открывается при нажатии на пункт списка, тогда должно все нормально работать.

Comment: Спасибо!! Проблему решил, только пришлось в фон вызываемых по нажатию фрагментов добавить цвет фона, чтобы перекрывали LIstView, и теперь всё отлично работает:))

Answer (score 1):

Вы не делаете фрагмент невилимым. Вы делаете невилимой некую вью.

Вам надо переопределить нажатие на назад и там сделать снова видимым спрятанное